# Проблема на странице входа Wordpress при использовании плагина All In One WP Security

Tags: wordpress

Я изменил страницу входа в Wordpress из /wp-admin в /login (используя плагин All In One WP Security)
  1. /login  открывается правильно, я могу заполнить логин и пароль для admin dashboard, но когда я нажимаю Submit, Wordpress перенаправляет меня на главную страницу.

Я не знаю, как решить эту проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Here is Russian Stackoverflow, please translate your question.

Comment: переводил на русский

Comment: Отозвал голос за закрытие вопроса

Comment: когда изменяю на /wp-admin работет отлично !!